# What statistical method to compare bilinguals and monolinguals on a task switching task?

Tags: methodology, dataset

I have data from my experiment where two groups participated (monolinguals vs. bilinguals).

There was a language switching as well as a task switching part to the experiment where the data tells how fast the participants responded as well as whether or not their answer was correct (correct vs. incorrect).

How should I analyse my data?

In addition> I HAVE looked at methods including: Two-way repeated measures ANOVA, IRT and some others but I don't feel like they apply to my case and I am therefore seeking inspiration and NOT for someone to do my homework as implied below.

PS: I am trying to see whether bilinguals perform better in task switching than monolinguals.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic - please summarize what methods you have considered, what are some pros and cons, etc - we're not here to do your homework.

Comment: The question would be more fit on [stats.se]

Answer (score 2):

You have not currently defined your hypothesis, but given what you describe, it is likely that you want to compare the two groups on speed and accuracy on the task switching task.

The simplest approach would be to use an independent groups t-test to compare whether the means of the groups differ significantly on your outcome measures (i.e., speed, accuracy).

Of course, all the usual issues about comparing two groups apply. In some case people would se a non-parametric test if they were particularly concerned about distributional assumptions.

There are also more sophisticated approaches to jointly modelling reaction time and accuracy. Check out this question: https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/660/52

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in the process model by Bishara et al. (2010). I have some (old and undocumented !) implementation at http://github.com/simkovic/toolbox which may be helpful.

In hindsight I would have preferred to implement the model in [STAN](http://mc-stan.org/) or some other probabilistic inference engine rather than to use (as the github repo does) the Maximum likelihood method proposed by Bishara & Co.

Bishara, A. J., Kruschke, J. K., Stout, J. C., Bechara, A., McCabe, D. P., & Busemeyer, J. R. (2010). Sequential learning models for the Wisconsin card sort task: Assessing processes in substance dependent individuals. Journal of mathematical psychology, 54(1), 5-13.